# A scope variable is updated after a popup to the user but not in a certain place

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, scope

I have the following initial code:

```
$scope.user = {'Name':'holl'};
$scope.tweet = {'message' : "Good job " + $scope.user.Name + "!! You have collected all there is..!"};
```

Later I call a function where user.Name is altered but $scope.tweet somehow is not altered and prints the old user name holl. I use the console to debug but the console is returning the updated name. I even use $scope.$apply() before sending the tweet (the console returns the updated version in this area) but no use. I don't understand why $scope.tweet stays the same. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding you are having a function that changes only `$scope.user`. But this wont change `$scope.user.Name` in the message of `$scope.tweet` because when the `$scope.tweet` is create the value of the `user.Name` is taken and converted to string and assigned to `tweet.message`. tweet.message won't get updated automatically.

So to solve this you have 2 options.

1) do the assignment to $scope.tweet again in the function where $scope.user is altered after the $scope.user is altered.

```
function X() {
    $scope.user = {'Name':'Jamie'};
    $scope.tweet = {'message' : "Good job " + $scope.user.Name + "!! You have collected all there is..!"};
}
```

or

2) Put $watch of $scope.user and assign the $scope.tweet inside watch function.

```
$scope.$watch('user', function(altered) {
    $scope.tweet = {'message' : "Good job " + altered + "!! You have collected all there is..!"};
});
$scope.user = {'Name':'holl'};
```